# Error in registering EC2 Instance-backed store

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

In trying to register an ami on Amazon EC2 with the following command:

ec2-register -n my-ami-prefix --cert /mnt/cert-aaa.pem --private-key /mnt/pk-bbb.pem mys3bucke/my-ami-prefix.manifest.xml

I get the following error:

Client.InvalidManifest: Invalid block device mapping: Invalid virtual name 'ebs5'

The mappings generated in the manifest are as follows:

```
<mapping><virtual>ami</virtual><device>sda1</device></mapping>
<mapping><virtual>ebs1</virtual><device>/dev/sdh</device></mapping>
<mapping><virtual>ebs5</virtual><device>/dev/sdi</device></mapping>
<mapping><virtual>ephemeral0</virtual><device>sdb</device></mapping>
<mapping><virtual>ephemeral1</virtual><device>sdc</device></mapping>
<mapping><virtual>ephemeral2</virtual><device>sdd</device></mapping>
<mapping><virtual>ephemeral3</virtual><device>sde</device></mapping>
<mapping><virtual>root</virtual><device>/dev/sda1</device></mapping>
```

According to the help text of the ec2-bundle-vol, the following are valid mapping names;

- "ami": denotes the root file system device, as seen by the instance.
- "root": denotes the root file system device, as seen by the kernel.
- "swap": denotes the swap device, if present.
- "ephemeralN": denotes Nth ephemeral store; N is a non-negative integer.

So, why is it creating "ebs" names for some of the mappings? Why is it giving these two devices the "ebs" name instead of the "ephemeral" name like the rest? When I run an "fdisk -l" all the device except the last have the same size. Can I go into the manifest and rename them to "ephemeral14" and "ephemeral15"?

Answer (score 1):

I added this to the bundle command, and at least it registered the AMI:

-B ami=sda1,root=/dev/sda1,ephemeral0=sdb,ephemeral1=sdc,ephemeral2=sdd,ephemeral3=sde,ephemeral4=sdh,ephemeral5=sdi

Comment: Worked for me. 
Thanks